# I was doing this SuperDataScience course and I got this "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')"

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_value = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean')

imputer = imputer.fit(X[ : , 1:3])        # This line is generating the error

X[ : , 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[ : , 1:3])
```

What should I do to deal with this error?

Comment: Have you tried with np.nan instead of 'NaN'?

Comment: Yup, tried np.nan too, didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
imputer.fit([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9]])
```

there is an error in using the parameters, should be `missing_values`

```
missing_values : number, string, np.nan (default) or None
```

Comment: As for the parameter ie missing_values string is acceptable and is accepted too. The problem is with the fitting part, that's where I need help